# How to insert a spark parquet into a HIVE Table?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hive, hiveql

I have a spark parquet table on disk with the following schema :

```
id1 : STRING
weight: array (nullable = true)
  |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
```

Using HIVE SQL, I want to insert this into a HIVE table.
However, when attaching as an External table, it fails.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nn.mytable1 (
        id1     STRING,
        weight  ARRAY <STRING>
    )    
    ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t'
    STORED AS PARQUET
    location "/user/xxxx/myfile/";
```

Is it related to casting an array of struct into an array of STRING?

Comment: Could you please share sample data also.

Comment: CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS nn.mytable1 (
        id1     STRING,
        weight  ARRAY <STRING>
    )    
     STORED AS PARQUET
    location "/user/xxxx/myfile/";

Comment: I mean remove "ROW FORMAT DELIMITED, FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\t' ", since you are saving spark parquet table as hive parquet table.

Comment: How the casting  array of Struct  --> Array of STRING is done in HIVE ?
is it automatic and smoothed ?